# Accessing local variable within same class python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to create a dataframe from excel files in remote desktop using Paramiko, but I failed to call `setPath()` to `writeDataframe()` and got this error

> TypeError: writeDataframe() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is my code :

```
class remoteConnection:
    def __init__(self,hostname, username, password, path):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.path = path

    def connectRemote(self):
        client = SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hostname=self.hostname,
                       username=self.username,
                       password=self.password,
                       look_for_keys=False,
                       allow_agent=False)
        sftp_handle = client.open_sftp()
        sftp_handle.chdir('.' + '/' + self.path)
        base_dir = sftp_handle.getcwd()
        return sftp_handle, base_dir

    def setPath(self, *pattern):
        current_sftp_handle , current_dir  = self.connectRemote()
        for i in pattern :
            current_sftp_handle.chdir(current_dir+'/'+str(i)+'/')
            updated_dir = current_sftp_handle.getcwd()
            return current_sftp_handle
    
    def writeDataframe(self):
        updated_sftp_handle = self.setPath()
        filename = [file for file in updated_sftp_handle.listdir()]
        appended_data = pd.DataFrame()
        for file in filename:
            f = updated_dir.open(file)
            temp_df = pd.read_excel(f)
            temp_df['Filename'] = file
            utime = f.stat().st_mtime
            temp_df['Date modified'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(utime)
            appended_data = appended_data.append(temp_df)
        return appended_data
```

I called my function like this:

```
    hostname='xxx.xxx.x.xxx'
    username='username'
    password1='XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    path1 = '/Documents/datasets'
    initClass = remoteConnection(hostname, username, password1, path1)
    connection = initClass.connectRemote()
    
    a = ['SOURCE A', 'SOURCE B']
    for i in a:
        my_obj = initClass.setPath(i)
        print(my_obj)
        
    dg = initClass.writeDataframe(my_obj)
```

Has anyone got any advice? Thanks

Comment: The example in your question doesn't give me the same error you have. Please, provide the simplest working example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you forgot to declare the argument or are passing an unneded argument:

Oprion 1: declare the argument:

```
def writeDataframe(self, arg):
```

Option 2: call the method without the arg:

```
dg = initClass.writeDataframe()
```